# Is there any development tool for WSO2 DAS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am trying to create analytics report using WSO2 DAS. Can anyone suggest me how we will move artifacts from dev to PROD for WSO2 DAS. Is there any development tool for WSO2 DAS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool as such for deployment. You can use an svn/git based model, where you commit the dev CAR artifact into svn/git and then pick the same up from PROD